# how to change illegal characters in php extract function?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, extract, scope

I needed to extract key-value pairs from the following array into variables

```
$data = array(
    'Quotation.id' => 1,
    'Quotation.project_id' => 2
);

extract($data);
```

Because the `.` is an illegal character in PHP, no extra variables are defined when I run `extract`.

I would like to somehow remove the dots and change the entire field into a camelCase. Meaning to say, without knowing in advance the keys in `$data`, I would like to somehow get back as newly-defined variables:

```
$quotationId = 1;
$quotationProjectId = 2;
```

How do I accomplish this?

Please ignore situations where the newly-defined variables may clash with existing variables. Assume this will not happen.

Comment: have you tried str_replace();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is probably an easier way with regular expressions, but this is how I would do it:

```
foreach ($data AS $k => $v) {
    $key = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('.', ' ', $k)));
    ${$key} = $v;
}
```

Comment: str_replace(array('.', '_'), ' ', $k) to also camelize project_id

Comment: Thank you! I just realized the key point in my question is to understand variable variables. Which can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php As for converting the name of the variables, that is less important.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.. saves other people from adding answers without a reason.

Comment: @DamienOvereem there was a time delay. I was told to wait for another 9 minutes before I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'Quotation.id' => 1,
    'Quotation.project_id' => 2
);

foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
   $keys = array_map('ucfirst',preg_split( "/(\._)/", $key ));
   $newKey = implode($keys);
   unset($data[$key]);
   $data[$newKey] = $value;
}

export($data);
?>
```